# Confused on math

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static int Alpha(){

    HashMap<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    map.put(1,5.5);
    map.put(67,1.4);
    map.put(9,7.8);
    map.put(24,6.4);


    int ans = -1;
    double best = 0.0;
     for(int i : map.keySet()){
    if(map.get(i) > best){
     best = map.get(i);
     ans = i;
     }
     }
     return ans;

    }
```

I don't understand why this returns 9. My logic is that the For-each loop goes through each key and with the If-statement it says: If for any one of these keys if it's greater than 0.0 set best equal to that number? The first number it sees in the key set that is greater than 0.0 is 1 so shouldn't best be 1?

I also don't understand the ans = i  line.  What does that do?

A piece by piece explanation of this *specific* code would be appreciated.

Comment: "if it's greater than 0.0" - no, if it's greater than the current value of best. Also, you don't stop once you've set best once. You keep going.

Comment: Use a debugger to find it out

Comment: Also, HashMaps don't provide ordering guarantees, and you're mixing up keys and values.

Comment: The answer is 9 because that's the key with the largest associated value (7.8).

Comment: One great way to find out what's happening is to `System.out.print` each variable in the loop. Then you can see how they change each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

your code is returning 9 because that is the key with the highest Value...

```
map.put(1, 5.5);
map.put(67, 1.4);
map.put(9, 7.8);   ///this
map.put(24, 6.4);
```

that is what your code is doing here in this condition

```
for (int i : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(i) > best) {
```